# Welche Präposition verlangt Bindung (Wechselkurs)?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Festlegt wurden hier unter anderem Wechselkursbandbreiten [...], um so Devisenspekulationen auszubremsen und Stabilität zu schaffen. Präsident Nixon hob 1971 schließlich die Bindung des Dollar **zu Gold** auf, 1973 wurden die Wechselkurse freigegeben.

- Bindung *an* plus Akkusativ, *zu* plus Dativ oder sind beide richtig? Hängt es vom Verb "aufheben" ab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es muss *die Bindung des Dollars **ans** Gold* heißen. Alternativ *zum Gold*.

Der Ausdruck *Dollar zu Gold* wäre als Überschrift in einer Tabellenspalte geeignet. An die hat der Autor hier vermutlich auch gedacht. Es passt hier aber inhaltlich nicht.

Comment: zum ersten Mal sehe ich "zu" mit Bindung als Präposition

Comment: Warum muss es *ans* (an das) Gold heißen? Geht es um bestimmtes Gold oder an Gold im Allgemeinen? Unspezifisch (und dabei eher *an* als *zu*) klingt es in meinen Ohren richtig.

Comment: @Phillip: Es war aber bestimmtes Gold. Nämlich welches, das die US-Notenbank besaß.

Comment: @Janka: sehe ich anders. Die Bindung an/zu Gold, nicht ans/zum Gold.